how to vertically center image in UIScrollView ? apple swift to pan zoom using UIViewRepresentable
I am quite new to UIKit, and I have encountered a layout issue that's driving me crazy.
my code is as follows, I want to create a view named ZoomableView which accepts an UIImage to pan & zoom.
I struggled to get it work at last, but How can I make the UIImage vertically centered in UIKit view ? am I going in the wrong direction ? there seems a lot of calculations, is there an easier way like the SwiftUI ?
import UIKit;
import SwiftUI;

struct ZoomableView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var image: UIImage
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var parent: ZoomableView
        var doubleTapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer?
        
        init(parent: ZoomableView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
            return scrollView.subviews.first
        }
        
        @objc func handleDoubleTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            if let scrollView = recognizer.view as? UIScrollView {
                if scrollView.zoomScale > scrollView.minimumZoomScale {
                    scrollView.setZoomScale(scrollView.minimumZoomScale, animated: true)
                } else {
                    let pointInView = recognizer.location(in: scrollView.subviews.first)
                    let newZoomScale = scrollView.maximumZoomScale
                    let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size
                    let width = scrollViewSize.width / newZoomScale
                    let height = scrollViewSize.height / newZoomScale
                    let originX = pointInView.x - (width / 2.0)
                    let originY = pointInView.y - (height / 2.0)
                    let rectToZoomTo = CGRect(x: originX, y: originY, width: width, height: height)
                    scrollView.zoom(to: rectToZoomTo, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        
        
        let scrollView = UIScrollView();
        
        scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0 // Set minimum zoom scale to 1.0
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 300)
        
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .red
        
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image);
        // ---
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        // ----
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        //
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        
        let doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(context.coordinator.handleDoubleTap(_:)))
        doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)
        
        context.coordinator.doubleTapRecognizer = doubleTapRecognizer
        
        // -----
        let imageSize = image.size
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let scale = screenWidth / imageSize.width
        let scaledHeight = imageSize.height * scale
        
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: scaledHeight)
        scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
        // ------
        
        
        return scrollView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
    }
}



for anyone bumps into this question, it is quite easy, just use anchor constraints (store it in coordinator, and remember to change constant when necessary.)
